# JS create objects with keys but no values

Tags: javascript

When iterating with a for loop it's more convenient to use this:

```
for (var key in obj){ key }
```

than these:

```
for (var i in array){ var key = array[i]; key }
for (var i = 0; i< array.length;i++){ var key = array[i]; key }
```

But, obviously, declaring arrays is easier:

```
var array = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

var obj =   { key1:'',key2:'',key3:'' }
```

Assuming I only care about keys and don't care about order, is there a way of declaring objects with just keys and no values (more easily than above)? I just don't like using

```
:'',
```

It looks like a  weird smiley face.

Edit:
`for-of` would definitely be the way to go, just not yet.

Comment: You might just be looking at an array then right ? If the values are empty why do you need it to be stored as an object anyways.

Comment: Is there some reason an array won't work for you?

Comment: You shouldn't use `for...in` loops to iterate over arrays fwiw.

Comment: @forgivenson because constant time lookups.

Comment: Objects are JS structures for key/value pairs. If you don't want key/value pairs use another structure like an array. For arrays you can use the even _more_ convenient `arr.forEach`.

Comment: @EricHartford But you aren't looking up anything, since you aren't storing anything but keys in the object.

Comment: @forgivenson Sure you are - you are looking up whether it exists in the data structure or not.

Comment: @Andy Objects are also good as HashSets.  If you value lookup speed over traversal order, Object with truthy values is the correct data structure to use.

Comment: Fair enough. But the OP hasn't explained why they want to do this, so speculation is pretty pointless.

Comment: I suppose it's speculation, but it's the only reason I can think of why someone would want to do this instead of using an arrray.

Comment: OP, perhaps you could explain _why_ you need this other than you don't want it looking "like a weird smiley face", because that's just daft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
var thing = ['a','b','c']
_.mapKeys(thing)
    Object {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}
_(thing).mapKeys().mapValues(_.constant(true)).value()
    Object {a: true, b: true, c: true}
```

Comment: for ( var key in _.mapKeys(thing) ) ?

Comment: If you just want to loop through the values, you can do: _.each(thing, function(n){// do something with n})

Comment: trying to stick with a for loop: python > ruby

Comment: I feel like typing them out is just better in every imaginable way

Answer (score 1):

ES5's official answer to this annoyance is the `forEach` method, which is built into the `Array` type. If you are using an Array and not an object, it accomplishes the same purpose, although it looks a bit different.

```
this.balls.forEach(function(ball) {
  this.space(ball);
}, this);
```

*(The `,this` ensures the right context of the `this` keyword)*

In ES6 with the arrow function, this is just:

```
this.balls.forEach(ball => {
  this.space(ball);
});
```

All versions of JavaScript define `for k in o` as a way of iterating keys, not array indexes or values, so it's something you'll want to avoid unless you're iterating through the keys of a dictionary.

Comment: Sadly the OP added this edit to the question "Edit: forEach is not the Answer, for-of would def be the way to go, just not yet."

Comment: @Andy Eugh...I had already seen that edit, but if your opposition to a particular approach is the wording used for it, you should write your own language that translates your own preference to another. `ayCaramba! --> .substring(`